# Span content clear the button beneath the span element

Tags: jquery

The body of the html has a `span` element and a `button` after it. The button click event should clear the span element and any key press should prepend the event key code to the span element. I'm using jQuery version 1.9.1.

What happens is, the `empty()` clears the span text *and* the button that is present after the span element as well. Kindly let me know what went wrong here.

```
function appendtext(event) 
{ 
    var keyCode = event.keyCode; 
    $("#spanid").prepend(keyCode); 
} 

$(document).keyup(appendtext); 

function clearfn() 
{ 
    ("#spanid").empty();
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces your problem. Is `("#spanid")` just a typo in your question?

Comment: Thank you Felix Kling. I have created one in jsfiddle.net. http://jsfiddle.net/planetsaro/xrryy/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` elements cannot be self closed, even if they have no content. If you do that, the browser will put the button *inside* the span element (*Right click `->` Inspect Element*).

With

```
<span id="spanid"></span>
```

it works as expected.